# How to factor a specific polynomial in a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to solve the problem about finite field in Chapter 15 in Artin's book.

It asks me to factor $x^9-x$ and $x^{27}-x$ in $\mathcal{F_3}$

From the proposition before that page, I know that it the irreducible polynomial should have degree that can divide 3 hence can only be $1$ and $2$

But when I try to factor it, I got  $\;x(x+1)(x-1)(x^6+x^4+x^2+1)$ , when I try to find the root of $(x^6+x^4+x^2+1)$, I find that all of $-1,\;0,\;1$ are not the root, which means the 6-degree poly is irreducible.

I tried annother way. I found that $x^9-x=x(x^4-1)(x^4+1)=x(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$

I cannot get the result I want and I am confused for the two factorization I got.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Knowing that a polynomial has no roots does not imply that it is irreducible.  Indeed $x^6+x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$.

Comment: Note that $(x^2+1)(x^4+1)=x^6+x^4+x^2+1$ which reconciles your two factorisations.

Comment: But you still have to check whether $x^4+1$ can be factorised. That means checking whether it could be the product of two quadratic factors and there is only one obvious pair to check.

Comment: OH thanks very much!  I used to believe no roots means irr, but now I get a counter example.

Comment: Really thanks @almagest. I got that. $x^4+1=(x^2+x+1)(x+1)^2 $ in $\mathcal{F_3}$

Comment: @longqianHuang No, this factorization doesn't work.

Comment: @Berci I am sorry but after calculating LHS does equal to RHS? And are there some good methods to perform the factorization ? I was stuck at $x^{27}-x$ since it has a much higher degree...